# How many processes are created

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, fork

I was wondering how many processes are created from fork() in this code, I did some trace and it's ended with 20 processes but I just can't be sure, can you help me please.
thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/types.h>

int main()
{
    **
    fork();
    fork();
    if( fork() > 0)
    {
        fork();
        fork();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why isn't 20 a satisfactory answer, especially since you appear to have already verified this fact?

Comment: Just before the `return`, print the pid and parent pid.  That will tell you how many processes and the parent/child tree.

Comment: To see the relation between the processes, print the result of `getpid()` and `getppid()`before `return 0;`

Comment: [here is a detailed example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-fork-produce-1-parent-3-child-processes/) of what the comments suggest you do...

Answer (score 4):

"See" how the number of processes evolves as each statement is executed:

```
/* before */     /* ... */             /* after */
/*      1 */     fork();               /*     2 */
/*      2 */     fork();               /*     4 */
/*      4 */     if (fork() > 0) {     /*     8 (4 go into the if) */
/*      8 */         fork();           /*    12: 4 (outside) + 8 (inside) */
/*     12 */         fork();           /*    20: 4 (outside) + 16 (inside) */
                 }
/*     20 */     /* ... */             /* total processes: 20 */
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's label all of the positions in which processes are created:

```
A:  fork();
B:  fork();
C:  if( fork() > 0)
    {
D:      fork();
E:      fork();
    }
    return 0;
```

And let's construct a tree showing all created processes and the fork label from which they are created:

[image]

In this tree, nodes depict the processes and the labels in the edges show the `fork()` call that created each child (e.g. proc. 1 created proc. 2 via fork A). If you count the nodes, you will see that they are in fact 20 processes. (Sorry for not following neither a strict BFS nor a DFS for my naming)

Comment: What did you use to draw this graph?

Comment: I used https://csacademy.com/app/graph_editor/   . Had to google search it though, didn't know it beforehand. Learning how to use it wasn't difficult.

Answer (score 1):

You can make each of your processes print a dot by adding the following line before `return 0`:

```
write(STDOUT_FILENO, ".", 1);
```

If you count the dots there is total of 20 processes, 1 of which is created when you start the program.

Comment: Maybe better? -- `printf("pid %d, ppid %d\n", (int)getpid(), (int)getppid());`

Comment: @pmg That can be less robust because now you have to consider what happens to `stdout` buffer when you `fork` and when it needs to be flushed.